# Log into Azure SQL using social logins

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

I have an ASP Core web app that connects to an Azure SQL database.
The users (a handfull of people) can log into the web app using Microsoft, Google or Facebook logins.

Since I've lost my appetite for developing web apps, I want to turn this app into a desktop app. 
This presents a number of problems, obviously, with regards to keeping the database credentials safe on the local machine where the app will be running.

I know the advice is to use a web service as data layer between the app and the database, but since I want to scale down my web development activities, not scale them up, this is not a preferred scenario.
I've looked at using DPAPI to encrypt the credentials, but that would mean the credentials need to be encrypted on the local machines. Ideally I'd encrypt them on my machine in a way they can't decrypt them. 
Since that's impossible, I don't think this scenario can work.

Ideally I'd have them connect to the database directly with unique credentials, without me having to manage all these accounts manually.

So, is there a way to have users login to Azure SQL using the same 'socials' they use to log in at the moment?

Cheers,
CJ

Comment: how are you going to manage who can modify what?

Comment: I had the same question as @MaartenDev also I think the best way is to follow the advise you mentioned and make your apis access your db, that's will be more secure and less maintenance in the future!

Comment: @MaartenDev All users have the same set of permissions, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Social login is not supported for SQL databases, you can use AD users though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-users-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities

Comment: I however think that you are solving the wrong problem, there is a reason everyone recommends adding an API. Creating a API isn't really "web development" it can be done in almost any language and requires no html/css at all. I think you should consider using an API because direct database access creates more problems then it solves

Comment: For example, how are you going to prevent users from deleting data from other users? How do you prevent users from updating data from other users, how do you prevent users from inserting massive amounts of data?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You're right, of course. With 'Web development' I meant having to create and maintain a Web app (in whatever language) as API layer. It's a hobby project and I simply don't like creating Web applications anymore. But I'll look into a ready made platform to create an API with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For instance, how will you prohibit users from removing data from other users.  To keep people from updating data from other users and from inputting enormous volumes of data.

As suggests in comment by [MaaretenDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6310593/maartendev) building API seems to be best suited. Create an API that will allow you to get greater sophistication and control over the database. Consider utilizing an API instead than direct database access since it causes more difficulties than it solves.

Else you can leverage Azure Active directory users to login so as to have the control.

> **Note**: The new admin name (user or group) cannot already be existing in the virtual master database as a server authentication
> user when setting up the Azure AD admin. If such an admin (name)
> already exists, the Azure AD admin setup will fail, rolling back its
> creation and notifying that such an admin (name) already exists.
> Because such a server authentication user is not a member of Azure AD,
> any attempt to connect to the server using Azure AD authentication
> fails.